# How to deploy docker container image updates from AWS ECR to ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

I’m new to both Amazon’s ECS *and* docker, and I don’t know how to deploy new images.

I currently create a new image in ECR with

```
NAME_TAG=my-image-name:my-tag-v1
ECR=my-acct-number.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

docker build -t $NAME_TAG .
docker tag -f $NAME_TAG $ECR/$NAME_TAG
$(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1) #log in
docker push $ECR/$NAME_TAG
```

At this point I don't know how to deploy the new container from ECR to my cluster.

I created the cluster, task and service using a Cloud Formation template, but updating the `TaskDefinition` image to `$ECR/$NAME_TAG` and running a stack update eventually times out and fails with a “service did not stabilize” error.

If I push to  `my-image-name:latest`, my cluster instances *do* pull down the new image, but they don’t run it, and in any case I want to avoid using the mysterious `latest` tag.

How am I supposed to deploy new images to ECS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to deploy your image using a new task definition every time you deploy.
The task definition lets you set the image version using the attribute "image"

```
"image":"my-acct-number.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-image-name:my-tag-v1"
```

In case you want to use only one task definition, you will have to build you image and tag it with whatever is defined in the the definition.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: Here's related information of deploying task definition service update using the `latest` tag (just beware this particular tag may cause confusion in other scenarios).